# Copying files containing specific text in its content from a folder to other

Tags: unix

At times I have come across a situation whereby I have to copy all the files containing a specific pattern in its content from a folder to another.

For example, `DirA` contains 100 files, out of which there are 60 files which contains a pattern `FOO`. My requirement is to copy these 60 files from `DirA` to `DirB`.

I typically write a small shell script to do this job and it works properly. However, I am trying to understand if there is a way to it only using a combination of some commands such that I need not write any shell script.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
cp `grep -l 'FOO' dirA/*` dirB/
```

`grep -l` will only output the name of the files matching the pattern.

Comment: Maybe you should add `-r` option to grep because orherwise the terminal complains saying that dirA/ is a directory

Answer (score 1):

Copying files containing specific content and preserving directory structure can be done by:

```
cp --parents `grep -lr 'text_content' ./*` /path/to/copy/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following script will work what you are looking for

```
cd /"path were file exist"
grep -w "word you want to search inside a file" "file.name/write nothing in case    multiple files" >/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then
     mv ls -ltr | grep your word /path to move on 

     fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your required files start with **FOO**

```
cp dirA/FOO* dirB
```